# HTML5 Canvas draw only visible images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Is it possible to "detect" and draw only visible images on HTML5 Canvas? This'll make a huge performance optimisation in my game, for example if image 1 is covered by  image 2, how can I only draw image 2 ?

Comment: Yes, with a lot of work and code.  Ray casting, occlusion culling, Bears, oh my!  Have you considered using an existing engine like Unity3D?

Comment: It seems you are using the `'2d'` context and render simple 2D graphics, e.g. tiles. If you give us a bit more information on that, we can give you better advice.

Comment: @DaveS Well my game is in 2D so I don't need Unity3D, however I'm using PIXI.JS library for fast rendering using WebGL

Comment: @le_m My game is an 2D isometric game built with Pixi.JS. It can contain a lot of entities / objects that can cover each other, so I want to add this optimisation to my game to improve performance when there's a lot of objects.

Comment: 2D flat would be easy to implement your own culling, isometric less so.

Comment: @DaveS Well if this can help, all the images are pre-rotated, I mean, it's just a basic drawImage() but with PIXI.JS

Comment: Do you have a z-order for each object so you know object 1 is drawn on top of object 2?  For basic culling you need that along with a bounding rectangle for each object.

Comment: @DaveS Of course I have a z-order property for each object and even a second z-order property if the first z-order is the same when calling `sort(a, b)`, and I also have the bounding rectangle

Comment: Using the answer given below. 10000 Sprites Render all 142ms. Cull and render, culled 2096 in 1567ms render remaining 114ms, Performance loss 1100% . For 1000 sprites, render all 18ms, Cull and render, culled 27, in 47ms render remaining in 17ms Performance loss 300% You need to be able to cull in under the time that it takes to draw approx 10% of the sprites and then you are just breaking even. Best place to find CPU cycles is in the code you have written, slash and burn, inline as many functions as possible, don't allocate don't delete. If that not work. rewrite counting CPU ticks as you go.

Answer (score 0):

This is dumb occlusion culling, not a fancy tree ordered collection of objects like in the original DOOM and such.

I have no idea whether the overhead of this method will pay off, you'll need to try it and see.  There might be a missing ; or {} or two.

```
count = count of all objects
for (i = 1; i < count; i++)
    visible[i] = true;
for i = 0; i < count; i++
{
    not_hidden = true;
    for (j = 0; j < count && not_hidden; j++)
    {
        if ((i!= j) && visible[j] 
            // if j is closer/on top -- reverse this if increased depth = -z not +z
            && (z-order[j] < z-order[i]) 
            // bounding rectangles 0,0 = top-left of screen
            && (obj[i].left <= obj[j].right) && (obj[i].right <= obj[j].right) && (obj[i].left >= obj[j].left)
            && (obj[i].top <= obj[j].bottom) && (obj[i].bottom <= obj[j].bottom) && (obj[i].top >= obj[j].top) )
        {
            visible[i] = false;
            not_hidden = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now only draw objects where visible[ix] is true